# Enable the cors in opendsitro for elasticsearch

Tags: reactjs

I installed opendistro for elastic search using docker and tried to fetch the information from opendistro kibana portal using react js, but I am getting an error about cors (Access-control-allow-origin):

```
Access to fetch at 'https://example.com/api/v1/auth/authinfo' from origin 'http://example.com:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

then added a few lines in elasticsearch.yml file:

```
 opendsitro_security.http.cors.enabled : true
 opendsitro_security.http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
 opendsitro_security.http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
 opendsitro_security.http.cors.allow-headers: X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type,Content-Length
 opendsitro_security.http.cors.allow-credentials: true
```

but still, I am getting the same error. My doubt is there any other way to enable cors in opendsitro for elastic search.

Comment: Don't know if you still need it, but you have a typo in your properties. Shouldn't be opendistro instead that opendsitro ?